# vector and matrix based in std:vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, visual-studio-2017, c++14

I am trying to inherit from std::vector to produce small usable classes for handling mathematical vector and matrices.

After some work this is an sketch of what I have obtained so far:

```cpp
#include <vector>
template<typename T>
struct vec : public std::vector<T> {
    using std::vector<T>::vector;   // to inherit the constructors
    vec(const std::vector<T> &v) :std::vector<T>(v) {}
    //vec() :std::vector<T>() {}    // it is needed?  
    vec &operator+=(const std::vector<T> &B) {
        auto ib = B.begin();
        for (auto i = this->begin(); i != this->end(); ++i, ++ib) {
            *i += *ib;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    friend vec operator+(vec a, const vec &b) { return std::move(a += b); }
};

template<typename T>
struct matr : public vec<vec<T>>
{
    using vec<vec<T>>::vec; // to inherit the constructors
    matr transpose() const {
        matr res(this->operator[](0).size(), vec<T>(this->size()));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i)
            for (size_t j = 0; j < res[0].size(); ++j)
                res[i][j] = this->operator[](j)[i];
        return std::move(res);
    }
    //matr(const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &M):vec<std::vector<T>>(M){}
    T operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const {
        return this->operator[](j)[i];
    }
    T &operator()(size_t i, size_t j){
        return this->operator[](j)[i];
    }
};

using namespace std;
int main() {
    vec<int> W1 = { 1,2,3 };             // ok only if vec inherits constructors from vector
    vector<int> W2 = { 1,2,3 };          // ok
    vec<int> W3 = W2;                    // ok but I had to define a constructor in vec from vector
    vec<vec<int>> M1 = { W1,W2 };        // ok only if vec inherits constructors from vector and explicit cast
    vector<vector<int>> M2 = { W1,W2 };  // ok!
    vector<vec<int>> M3 = { W1,W2 };     // ok!
    matr<int> M3b = { W1,W2 };           // ok!
    matr<int> M4 = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} }; // ok only if vec inherits constructors from vector
    //vector<vector<int>> M5 = M4;       // KO it works if matr is declared also public vector<vector<int>>
    matr<int> M6 = M4+M4;                // Ok but only if vec defines it's own constructor ¿?. 
                                         // Shouldn't matr inherit the operator+ from vec in any case?
    matr<int> M7 = M1;                   // Ok but I had to define a explicit cast in vec
    //matr<int> M8 = M2;                 // KO no idea
    matr<int> M9 = M3;                   // Ok if v
    matr<int> M10 = M9.transpose();      // Ok (std::move works)
    vec<int> a = M10[2];                 // OK but there are problems if multiple inheritance 
    int b = M10(1, 2);                   // OK    idem
    M10(1, 2) = 4;                       // OK    idem
    // b = M10[1,2];                     // KO no idea as how to define it. 
}
```

My main question is about how to make work the lines defining M5 and M8 without disturbing the others. M5 compiles if matr  inherits both from `vec<T>` and from `vector<vector<T>>` but then I have a lot of ambiguity problems. For M8 I tried to create a constructor in matr without success, when I uncomment it several of the other lines stop working (M3b and M4 at least).

I have been using C++ to code some problems and algorithms whenever I need it for a long time, but I have very little experience in classes, and I'm not a professional programmer so I'm sorry if this is a silly question. I'm using VC++2017 or G++ 8.2 with --std=gnu++14, and I always try to compile in both.

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: Also why are you inheriting from `std::vector` instead of having a class member?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: `std::vector` evolves with the language, and already implements a lot of useful constructors which I don't how to code, and that did not exist when I started programming in C++, I just want to profit from future advances in the language, in addition it is not only vectors I'm interested in, I would like to know how inherit from any container or predefined class, by the same reason.  Sorry for the multiple question, I'm going to remove all the second part.

Comment: It is easier if you have a class called Matrix and implement operator overloading and copy constructor etc...

Comment: Perhaps the old [std::valarray](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) can be of use?

Comment: @Esteban - As in the last paragraph of your question, you mention that you want to use matrices and vectors just as a mean to an end, to solve some problems of yours, may I ask whether you did consider using one of the existing linear algebra libraries (Armadillo, Blitz, Eigen) instead of writing your own from scratch ? IMHO writing such a thing from scratch would be a very time consuming endeavour.

Comment: `std::vector` does not have a virtual destructor, making inheriting from it a Really Bad Idea (tm).

Comment: @jpmarinier before writing my minilibrary I looked and tried the boost library  and it is,  I think, mostly for numeric analysis, it is huge and has lots of functions and functionalities, while my use is more for small integer matrices or matrices with coefficients in a ring and the kind of algorithms I need are relatively simple and fun to code, and I'm not even sure that they are implemented in boost!.